# Picking a random element from a Multidimensional Array

Tags: c#, arrays, random, console-application

Please Does anyone know how to pick a random element from an array?

I know how to implement on normal Variables

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int no = rnd.Next(30);
Console.WriteLine(no);
```

but i need to implement it on an array.

Comment: What do you mean by "implement random on an array"? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Do you want to *fill* an array? *shuffle* an array? Or pick a *random element* from an array? Or...?

Comment: @MarcGravell - I think the OP wants to _implement_ `Random` on an array.

Comment: @Oded ah, I think you've nailed it there. Thanks for clarifying ;p

Comment: @MarcGravell YES that what i want to do

Comment: @Precious1tj - Which one of the 3 things that Marc asked?

Comment: @Marc, well you did write `or`, should have expected a boolean.

Comment: @Precious those were different, separate options...

Comment: @Oded Pick a random element from an array

Comment: @Mike I could have been assuming bitwise integer math... A `[Flags] enum`, if you will

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of how to pick a random element from an array.

```
int[] possible = new int[] { 0, 5, 10, 15 };
Random r = new Random(); 
int a = possible[r.Next(possible.length)];
```

However, I should note that if you call this repeatedly, make sure you only call the last line multiple times. Calling the second line every time could result in repeated results, as Random() uses the current time as a seed. If the time hasn't changed, you'll get the same result multiple times.

At OP's request: on a two dimensional array:

```
//Assuming possible is an int[,]
Random r = new Random(); 
int a = possible[r.Next(possible.GetLength(0)), r.Next(possible.GetLength(1))];
```

Comment: Pls how will i do this in a multidimensional array

Comment: I've updated to include a sample of how to apply it to an `int[,]`. It should be enough to show you how to apply it to your code.